# ARM disassembly

Tags: arm

Is there a tool which analyzes and can highlight what each line of code means. I am not looking for a decompiler like that of Hex-Rays Decompiler. I am looking for a simple tool that shall be of assistance in reading the assembly code.

Answer (score 17):

What about using [objdump](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html)?

```
$ cat add.c 
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -O2 add.c

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d add.o

add.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <add>:
   0:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
   2:   4770        bx  lr
```

It can provide source code mixing as well if your object file contains debug information (gcc -g) and if you supply -S to objdump.

Comment: The ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual) for the specific architecture (or get a newer one as it will specify architecture differences) details what each instruction means.  objdump + ARM ARM is all you need.

Comment: Agreed. The tool is to supplement and to save those precious few minutes when you are running a tight schedule.

Comment: the instruction set is not complicated, with one glance through the document, you wont normally need to go back.  You could have learned the instruction set several times over in the time it took to look for and wait for an answer to this question.

Comment: Again, agreed. Its for occasional use by me and other colleagues who don't have to view dis(assembly) on a daily basis.

Comment: If you can compile the code with debugging symbols, that helps too (gcc -g).

Answer (score 11):

The Online Disassembler (ODA) supports ARM and a myriad of other architectures. You can enter binary data in the Live View and watch the disassembly appear as you type, or you can upload a file to disassemble. A nice feature of this site is that you can share the link to the disassembly with others.

http://www.onlinedisassembler.com

Comment: "Maximum upload size is 256KB" :(

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your question, IDA Pro can disassemble ARM too.
Besides, have you tried [ARM DS-5 Development Studio](http://ds.arm.com/)?
Some features are more hardware-related, but the IDE (Eclipse) is very nice.

Features:

- Debug support for bare-metal, RTOS, Linux, and Android platforms
- Non-intrusive cycle-accurate ETM and PTM instruction tracing
- Seamless support for SMP systems
- Automated debug sessions for faster debug cycles
- ITM and STM instrumentation tracing
- Support for pre-configured and custom platforms

In the manual it says it contains:

- DS-5 Debugger, covering all stages of product development
- ARM Compiler 5.04 for embedded and bare-metal code
- Linaro GCC Toolchain 2013.03 for Linux applications and Linux kernel
- ARM Streamline™ Performance Analyzer for various operating systems, including Linux, Android and RTX
- Eclipse IDE, source code editor and project manager
- Fixed Virtual Platforms (FVP) for Cortex™-A8 and quad-core Cortex-A9 processors
- Example projects and documentation

Answer (score 2):

What about this free program :: http://pel.hu/armu/

Comment: Websense blocks the URL :"-(